# How do I find interior angles of Irregular pentagon with known lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

I have an irregular pentagon with known lengths. I am trying to understand how to calculate the interior angles.

The lengths are as follows, connecting in the following order:

L1 = A, 
L2 = B, 
L3 = C, 
L4 = C,
L5 = B

It looks like a barn roof. :-)

How can I go about finding the interior angles, as a function of the segments?  Also note, It is symmetric around the mid point of L1 and the point connecting L3 and L4. That would provide a new 4 sided polygon, with known 90 degree angle and a new, unknown length. The other lengths would be L1/2,  L2, L3 but I'm not sure of its usefulness.

I know the sum of interior angles is 540 degrees for the pentagon and 360 for the the other one.

Maybe there is some way to divide the pentagon into three triangles and calculate the angles from that?

Thanks

Comment: You can't, there are more than one pentagons with given side lengths. You need one more piece of information (e.g. "height" of the pentagon wrt $L_1$) or constraint (e.g. the pentagon is concyclic ) to pin down the pentagon.

Comment: The lengths are fixed and laid out in a specific order, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5.  Not in a different order that would make a different pentagon. If the lengths are fixed and connected in a specific order, I am not seeing how there could be different pentagons?

Comment: Trying to think of other constraints.  The sum of L2+L3+L4+L5 is greater than L1.  Can not be equal to or less than L1.   The sum of L2+L3 is equal to L4+L5.  L2+L3 is greater than 1/2*L1.

Comment: Start from a $2 \times 1$ rectangle with bottom edge $L_1 = 2$, vetical edges $L_2 = L_5 = 1$. split the top edge into two horizontal edges $L_3 = L_4 = 1$, you get a degenerate pentagon with $(A,B,C) = (2,1,1)$. Start from an equilateral triangles with side $2$, set the bottom edge to $L_1 = 2$, split the two other edges into 4 edges of length $1$, you get another degenerate pentagon with same $(A,B,C) = (2,1,1)$.

Comment: Following the excellent remarks of @achille hui, you can consider fixing one angle $a$ and see if you can build such a pentagon (with angles that will be functions of $a$).